# WPF Custom Control Style Trigger Not Working

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

Special thanks to @BionicCode for getting me started here with my user control styling:
[Styling A Custom Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668082/styling-a-custom-control/77668378#77668378)

I created a simple demo custom control with a button and textblock. Now I'm adding a style for the button.

First, I added a ComponentResourceKey in the code file:

```
public static ComponentResourceKey ButtonStyleKey = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(MyCustomControl), "ButtonStyle");
```

Next, I added the button style to my Generic.xaml file

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static local:MyCustomControl.ButtonStyleKey}" 
   TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

<Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEEEE"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 5"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />

<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            
            <Grid>

                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>

                <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
            </Grid>
            
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2 1" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            
        </ControlTemplate>
        
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Here's the button in the control template

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" 
    x:Name="button"
    Height="65"
    Width="150"
    Content="A Button"
    Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:MyCustomControl.ButtonStyleKey}}"/>
```

The problem is with the IsPressed trigger. The background color does not change to red.

The MouseOver trigger works fine and sets the button's background to orange, and the IsEnabled trigger sets the colors for disabled as well, so I know the style is working ok otherwise.

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77679848/3141792) is correct. Triggers or XAML markup in general is executed in their order of declaration. This is because WPF simply parses the XAML document line by line and converts it to C# code. The order of declaration is also important when you merge resources. Or declare resources (there is no forward declaration, so in order for resource A to be able to reference resource B (e.g., a Brush), resource B must be declared before resource A. Or you overlay elements (using Z-Index). Declaration order in XAML matters.

Comment: I recommend looking into the VisualStateManager. It's the recommended way to implement visual states and offer more flexibility compared to triggers. One big advantage is that VisualStates are mutual exclusive. this means your current issues could have been avoided had you used the [VisualStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#examples).

Comment: [How to create a template for a control (WPF.NET): Use a VisualState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-apply-template?view=netdesktop-7.0#use-a-visualstate), [Creating a Control That Has a Customizable Appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/creating-a-control-that-has-a-customizable-appearance?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: I have also to point out that `DynamicResource` is very expensive. You should avoid it and only use it if you dynamically replace the referenced resource at runtime. Always prefer `StaticResource`. There are many reasons to avoid `DynamicResource`. For example, in your case the resource is in the themes resource dictionary. This means, any exception that are caused by this resource will be thrown at runtime. For this reason, you should also consider declaring the resource in the application resource dictionary instead.

Comment: Don't I need to make it dynamic if I want the end uer to be able to replace the style later on?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If the `Button` is inside the default template of a custom control, then the reference to the resource has to be dynamic (as there is no forward declaratio9n in XAML). Because you had only posted a snippet (the `Button`) the context was not clear to me. So, I made the more general statement about `DynamicResource` so that you can reevaluate the usage as you know the full context of the Button. Due to the lack of context, I was not able to determine if `DynamicResource` is a bad choice in this case. It potentially was. I just left that decision to you.

Comment: But you are right, if this button is inside the theme dictionary and the referenced resource is expected to be overridden externally, then you must reference it using `DynamicResource`.

Comment: If I threw a small sample project up on GitHub, would you review it for me? I'd like to know that I'm going in the right direction. I added a bit to your example

Comment: If it's not too big. I can check it tomorrow or the day after. I'm sorry if I confused you or made you feel insecure about your project. I just wanted to help as good as I can. I will find some time tomorrow and review your current version as you asked for, I'm happy to help. Maybe you have a preference about where I should focus on.

Comment: On the contrary - you cleared up a lot of confusion on my part. My demo is here https://github.com/MaroisConsulting/MyCustomControl.git. It's very small. Please see About.txt. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I will take a look later. I will also provide a small example on how to theme a control. You are already almost there now.

Comment: Hi Bionic. Just following up to see if you had any more thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I have already reviewed it. I think I will make a small example of application theming tomorrow. Will push a dedicated branch to your repository. Alongside a text file with some annotations (code is commented too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the IsMouseOver will triumph IsPressed since IsMouseOver is defined after IsPressed

try switching them

```
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2 1" />
            </Trigger>
```

if you want to have different behavior when IsMouseOver and IsPressed is true simultaneously you should look into MultiTrigger